# How do I configure /etc/hosts and /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini for sendemail

Tags: php, sendmail

I installed sendmail on my Ubuntu 12.04 web-server. I also configured the [mail function] and I tried to send emails...the message from the php code I wrote told me that the email has been send successfully but, there is nothing received in my emails. I also tried to look at some solved problems ...... I came across an advise that suggests to edit /etc/hosts file but I am confused identifying between localhost and localdomain .. my virtual machine (webserver) name is ABC-HR-System, my hostname (after i run the command hostname is) xyz. What can i do to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The email function is rather slow, i have had them take 20+ minutes to show up in my inbox, it probably varies with your isp, also check your spam folder
You may want to look at this project:
https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer
these are the files it needs `class.phpmailer.php`, `class.pop3.php`, and `class.smtp.php`
i have used it and it works, version 5.2.1